# Command to return package version or empty string

Tags: apt, bash, dpkg

I'm looking for a simple command that prints the package version, *only* if the package is installed.

If the package is not installed (or is not a valid package), I want the output to be an empty string.

This is what I've come up with so far. Unfortunately, it only works in cases when the package exists.

```
dpkg-query --showformat="\${Version}" --show ubuntu-desktop 
1.469
```

However, when the package does *not* exist, the output is an error message. I would like the output to be blank or empty in this case.

```
dpkg-query --showformat="\${Version}" --show ubuntu-desktopX
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ubuntu-desktopX
```

How can I achieve this?

UPDATE 1

Can we achieve this without using redirection (i.e. `2>/dev/null`)?

UPDATE 2

A true/false result would be fine as well, since I can always get the package version using the above, if the result is true.

Comment: The *output* probably *is* empty; the message `dpkg-query: no packages found matching ubuntu-desktopX` goes to the error stream `stderr`

Comment: Indeed, you are right. Thanks for pointing that out. Nevertheless, let me add the restriction that I do not want to redirect stderr to `/dev/null`. Curious if someone can come up with something.

Comment: At the end of the day aren't you seeking for True/False rather than Something/Nothing?

Comment: Now that you bring it up, true false would work. (I can always get the package version if the result is true).